# How can I programmatically open (show in screen) NavigationView

Tags: android, material-design, navigationview

How can I programmatically open (show in screen) NavigationView?
I can't find any function what can be helpfull.

I have this xml file:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    //...

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:itemTextColor="#333"
        app:itemIconTint="#333"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer_items" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need have reference to DrawerLayout

```
drawerLayout.openDrawer();
drawerLayout.closeDrawer();
```

use openDrawer and closeDrawer to change menu visibility

Comment: yes, thank you) I used drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT)

Comment: `drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.START)` is preferable

Comment: @deathangel908 Why `drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.START)` is better then openDrawer ? I think openDrawer() is much more readable.

Comment: So it could go right in case if a person choose left hand locale.

Answer (score 9):

To improve the code:

```
drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
```

Answer (score 1):

```kotlin
drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.END)
drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END)
```