# Kotlin: Redirecting from an activity to another activity

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I want to redirect my card to another activity but I don't know how.

activity_main.xml

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                app:cardElevation="6dp">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/card2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/dashboad_item_2_background">

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/end_view_background"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageIcon2"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/icon_background"
                        android:contentDescription="Descrizione 2"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/pantografo"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textItem2Title"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
                        android:text="Test"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageIcon2"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imageIcon2" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textItem2Description"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:maxLines="2"
                        android:text="Descrizione 2 qui"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/textItem2Title"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/textItem2Title"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textItem2Title" />


                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
   class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

I want to redirect all the CardView, is there a way?
I searched a lot, without a solution.

I tried to add an "android:onclick" but I don't know how to use it since I'm new in Android Studio and Kotlin.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't tell what you want to do, what do you mean by redirecting? What do you want to use OnClick for?

Comment: @Merthan E When the user clicks on the CardView element, I want to redirect him to another activity (for example: MapsActivity)

Comment: Added an answer, tell me if that doesnt solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/use-view-binding-to-replace-findviewbyid-c83942471fc

First off, you need a way to access the view and Viewbinding is the current best practice

Once you have access you need to use intents to navigate to the second activity (you should set the listener in onCreate)

```
cardview.setOnClickListener {
    val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, MapsActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

Comment: It works! Can you suggest me a way to open the drawer navigation menu? Thanks!

Comment: That depends on a lot of other stuff and I'm not an expert on that, maybe this answer helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32122621/how-can-i-programmatically-open-show-in-screen-navigationview If it doesn't, you probably have to look into drawers in general so that might take 2-5 hours

Comment: Hi there. The binding method is too slow. When I click on the card, the app loads for too long time

Comment: Very unlikely that it's due to the binding, as any kind of onclicklistener is really fast.

Maybe your new screen is doing something in the background